# Unity editor and project settings and preferences turned pink?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was working on my project, a few hours ago. But now, when I opened my unity editor everything was pink. I tried opening the project settings, but that was pink also, everything was pink. And I was not able to find the render pipelone option in the edit settings.. how should I fix this. It's driving me crazy now ... And I have almost completed my game. Pls help someone .. :( and also I don't have a graphics card because I am just 13 years old and just started unity

Comment: `I don't have a graphics card because I am just 13 years old and just started unity` .. that's some strange reasons for not having a graphics card ^^ How did you almost complete your game so far? In general if working on a serious project I suggest you always use some sort of **version control** like e.g. [GIT](https://git-scm.com/) (it's completely free) .. in order to be able to track your latest changes and revert in case of emergency ;)

Comment: Well, in my game, there are 4 enemy, 1 player, a bridge and a house so I guess it worked without graphics card. And while I was adding a bit of trees and grasses, that time it turned pink. So is there any way, to fix this bug outside unity because the project settings, the preferences, and everything's pink.

Answer (score -1):

I think your color preferences has changed. Try this: Go to Editor > Preferences > Colors and check Scene tab. If you see the color pink, change it. These are my color preferences for scene:

[image]

Comment: Well, my preferences is also pink . What should I do ?